# iOS: SVProgressHUD not displayed correctly

Tags: ios, svprogresshud

I have called `SVProgressHUD` on `viewDidLoad` as follows:

```
[SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Loading"];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
{
    if ([data length] > 0 && error == nil)
    {
       //do some task
        [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
    }
}];
```

But here is what I get: `SVProgressHUD` is not showing up. Where am I getting wrong?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be that you're calling the show and dismiss methods from a thread other than the main thread. This causes weird issues when you need access to the GUI. When you call the show/hide methods outside of the main thread, use this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Loading"];
});

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
});
```

Comment: i get linker error when I use the above code ERROR:Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_dipsatch_async", referenced from:..

Comment: It's a typo. It should be dispatch (not dipsatch).

Comment: Oh yes that was a typo. But with your solution, progressHUD comes n goes very fast, without the loading image.

Comment: Is it possible the request is completed that fast?

Comment: Nope, the progressHUD disappears and I get a blank screen for a long time and then the result is displayed. Plus the progressHUD is seen same as the picture posted above.

Comment: it might be because you didn't specifically set the type of progress view you wanted

Comment: So what do I need to specify? Please let me know. Even if I specify MaskType, progressHUD gives a square box with nothing loading in it.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you haven't copied the images in correctly. There's a `.bundle` containing the images - is that definitely in your project? Also, make sure you have `QuartzCore` linked

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed adding **SVProgreeHUD.bundle** file. Because it is required to display image overlays and also success and error statuses.